# Adicionar um botão dentro de um Textview

Tags: android, textview

Tenho um texto no final do texto estou querendo colocar um botão ver mais, tem como colocar tipo um hyperlink ou tem que criar um botão mesmo do lado do `Textview` ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vejo que você trabalha com tamanhos dinâmicos, minha sugestão é colocar esse Textview dentro de uma ListView, assim o tamanho será realocado conforme seu texto. @IlgnerdeOliveira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode atribuir dos parâmetros no seu `TextView` que farão com que eles possam funcionar como botões.

`android:clickable="true"` isso você irá dizer que o seu `TextView` tem função de botão

`android:onClick="selecionarOpcao"` isso irá chamar uma função da sua `Activity` contento a funcionalidade que você desejar.